# Filter array of objects based on property value, and remove some properties from remaining objects

Tags: javascript

I want to remove multiple items of an object from my array any built in function can help me to solve my problem :

Array is :

```
this.array= [ 
    { "Id": 1, "Title": "3 man crew –Distribution", "checked": true,'data': 123},
    { "Id": 2, "Title": "3 man crew – Transmission" ,'data': 123}, 
    { "Id": 3, "Title": "Flagger",'data': 124 },
    { "Id": 1, "Title": "Mowing Crew" ,'data': 183}
    { "Id": 7, "Title": "Mowing Crew3" ,'data': 187}
]
```

I want to remove **Id** and **Data** from my filtere array if input is 1  so my new array is:

```
[ 
    { "Title": "3 man crew –Distribution", "checked": true},
    { "Title": "Mowing Crew" ,'data': 183} 
]
```

app.html:

based on the id delete the array :

```
**app.ts**

deleteCheck(value) {
    //logic to delete id and data 
    this.array = this.array.filter(item => item.Id=== value);
    // returns array but with Id and but i want my new array without data and id
}
```

Comment: Why would you think this has anything to do with Angular?

Comment: Are you trying to remove the properties from existing object or create a new object without the properties?

Comment: I'd suggest you go back and review your JavaScript tutorials and intros again. What you are trying to do is extremely trivial. It's just filtering and mapping, which is what JavaScript does for a living.You're not going to get very far very fast if you have to post to SO every time you want to do a little data manipulation.

Comment: @torazaburo  i tried with that too but was stuck thats why i posted here to elaborate my issue, always appreciate every question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `map` function:

```
var newArray = array
    .filter(item => item.Id === value)
    .map(item => ({ 
        Title: item.Title, 
        checked: item.checked 
    }));
```

Comment: @torazaburo filtering is not an OPs question as he knows how to use `filter(...)` function.

Comment: it returns undefined if not matched

Comment: I might prefer to write this as `.filter(({Id} => Id === value).map(({Title, checked}) => ({Title, checked}))`.

Comment: And note that this copies *only* Title and checked. This does not extend automatically

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), you should also use [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), like this:

```
deleteCheck(value) {

//logic to delete id and data 
    this.array = this.array.filter(item => item.Id === value)
          .map(item => {
              delete item.Id;
              delete item.Title;
              return item;
          });
}
```

Comment: I'm not a huge fan of using `map` as a way to mutate an object via side-effects such as `delete`.

Answer (score 1):

Probably map:

```
.map( ({Id, data, ...rest}) => rest);
```

Note that this is quite new cool stuff ( object destructuring with an rest operator), but it [works](http://jsbin.com/mucufurere/edit?console) , at least on modern browsers...